# No tracking with Microtype + russian babel + mathdesign

Tags: babel, microtype

I'm trying to compile the following code based on "more realistic example" from microtype.sty manual, Sect. 5.3.  It works without babel (or with, say, french option) or without mathdesign.  But with both them present, I get equal tracking for all 3 input lines.

How can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[mdbch,expert]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[babel=true,tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}
   { encoding = *,
     size     = {-small,Large-},
     font     = */*/*/sc/* }
\SetTracking[ no ligatures = f ]{ encoding = *, shape = sc}{ 100 }
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, size = -small }{  800 }
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, size = Large-  }{ -100 }

\begin{document}

\textsc{this is a test}  $abcd$

{\footnotesize this is a test}

{\Large this is a test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Charter font provided by **mathdesign** is not available in T2A encoding; so the test you try to do does not work, probably because **microtype** gets confused with the font substitutions.

Without the `expert` option and with a different language not using the cyrillic script, the result is what's expected.

A tip: always put the call of **fontenc** *before* loading **babel**, particularly when using cyrillic encodings.

As you point out in the comment there's also a glitch with **mathdesign** that declares the T1 encoding. However, with Russian **babel** the encoding active after `\begin{document}` is correctly T2A. However a loading order such as

```
\usepackage[<options>]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

is recommended, so that the T2A encoding, which is specified last, is the default encoding. Always call **inputenc** *after* **fontenc**.

Comment: Isn't it true that mathdesign affects mostly math fonts? I found the only line with reassignment of `\rmdefault` -- but if I change it back to `cmr`, nothing happens.

Comment: No, with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` (the same as `mdbch`, but friendlier) you're asking that the font is Charter for the whole document, text included. Only math is affected with `russian` because the cyrillic Charter font is not available, so LaTeX changes the text family back to Computer Modern.

Comment: Also if I provide `t2amdbch.fd` with references to my localized Charter analogue, still nothing

Comment: Ah, I see! `mathdesign` in its last lines requires `[T1]{fontenc}`, and loading it before `[T2A]{fontenc}` solves the problem.  Thank you for pointing me to it!